# File sharing through Telegram

Tags: javascript, telegram, embed, file-sharing

I am trying to embed audio files from my public Telegram channel in my web project using the src attribute in the audio tag. However, I cannot obtain a direct link for those files and my attempts to do so have failed. How can I embed the audio files from my Telegram channel into my web project without uploading the files to another platform? I want to directly embed the audio files from my Telegram channel.